# Maven plugin to output class dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I am looking for a tool, ideally a maven plugin, which can analyse a project and outputs a dependency graph. The graph would show the dependencies between classes, and the output format would be exploitable by a program.

I would like to generate this graph automatically after compiling a project.

Do you have some leads? Thank you.

**Clarification**: I'm not looking for dependencies between maven artifacts, but between classes in my own project (inter-class dependencies)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only directly usable tool through Maven I can think of is [JDepend](http://www.clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html).  However, the maven plugin itself will only generate an HTML report, and at an initial glance I'm not sure how easy it will be to parse.

However, JDepend can produce XML when run through Ant, which can easily be done with the [Maven AntRun Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/).

Another Maven running Ant solution could be with the [Eclipse Metrics Plugin](http://metrics.sourceforge.net/).  On top of being an easy to use eclipse plugin, it also has instructions for running through Ant.

The only two other dependency analysis solutions I can think of probably won't fit what you're doing.  One is Sonar, which has a fairly comprehensive design view which shows dependencies at a library, package, and class level.  However, this is only accessible through a web interface.  The other is with [Google's Java Analytix](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/codepro/doc/index.html) tool, which has the ability to [generate a dependency chart and report](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/codepro/doc/features/dependencies/dependencies.html).

Answer (score 2):

Two plugins exists for the purpose

- [el4j](http://el4j.sourceforge.net/plugins/maven-depgraph-plugin/plugin-info.html)
- [maven-graph-plugin](http://mvnplugins.fusesource.org/maven/1.0/maven-graph-plugin/index.html)

On the link, you can find a simple usage of these plugins.

Comment: I wan't looking for dependencies between maven artifacts, but between classes in my own project (inter-class dependencies). I'll clarify this in the question